# What does the scope attribute from the action tag of the struts-config file mean?

Tags: java, scope, struts, struts-1, struts-config

I'm working on a Struts application.

In order to edit the `struts-config.xml` file, I think I have to add an attribute - `scope`, in the action tag. I'm not sure about its meaning, or its usage.

```xml
<action path="/WetsVpnSwapTraffic"
            type="com.kpn.bop.web.action.vpn.wets.WetsVpnSwapTraffic"
            scope="request"
            name="WetsVpnSwapTrafficForm"
            roles="bop_wetsvpn_migrate"
            validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="/WetsVpnSwapTrafficValidate.do"/>
        <forward name="failure" path="/WetsVpnList.do"/>
</action>
```

Can anyone explain me if I have to put this attribute?

Answer (score 8):

The attribute `scope` is used to define the scope (life of the object, the form) of the object action form that used in that action configuration.

There's also different scopes, `page`, `request`, `session`, `application`. That's all from servlet specs. If you specify the scope of request that you want the form object is available during servlet http request.

You can check this [reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20100215014434/http://www.jajakarta.org/struts/struts1.2/documentation/ja/target/userGuide/building_model.html#javabeans) to determine how to use scopes.

There's also link to [action mapping configuration](https://web.archive.org/web/20171021062122/http://www.jajakarta.org:80/struts/struts1.2/documentation/ja/target/userGuide/building_controller.html#config).

Comment: (With the caveat that in the context of the question only "request" and "session" scopes are useful.)

Answer (score 2):

It determines if the `ActionForm` is in the request or session.